# Can I derive from a class that can only be created by a "factory"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, factory, api-design

Suppose that a library I'm using implements a class

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, private_API_args):
        ...
```

It's meant to be instantiated only via

```
def factory(public_API_args):
    """
    Returns a Base object
    """
    ...
```

I'd like to extend the `Base` class by adding a couple of methods to it:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def foo(self):
        ...
    def bar(self):
        ...
```

Is it possible to initialize `Derived` without calling the private API though?

In other words, what should be my replacement for the `factory` function?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any access to the private API, you can do the following thing:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, private_API_args):
        ...


def factory(public_API_args):
    """ Returns a Base object """
    # Create base object with all private API methods
    return base_object


class Derived(object):
    def __init__(self, public_API_args):
        # Get indirect access to private API method of the Base object class
        self.base_object = factory(public_API_args)

    def foo(self):
        ...
    def bar(self):
        ...
```

And now in the main script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# create the derivate object with public API args
derived_object = Derived(public_API_args)

# to call private API methods
derived_object.base_object.method()

# to call your method from the same object
derived_object.foo()
derived_object.bar()
```

Comment: But you don't have the inheritance any more: you can't use Derived instances like you did Base instances. That's really the whole point.