# Constructor for a class whose super should only be made via factory method

Tags: java, constructor, factory-method

I have the following class:

```
public class Foo(){
    int parameter;
    static Set<Foo> cache=new HashSet<Foo>();
    public Foo(int parameter){
        this.parameter=parameter;
        addToCache(this);
    }
    public static Foo Factory(int parameter){
        Foo duplicate=findDuplicate(parameter);
        if (duplicate!=null){
            return duplicate;
        }else{
            return new Foo(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that calling `Foo`'s constructor directly will add to the static cache. 
I now need to subclass this object to add some functionality.

```
public class Bar() extends Foo{
    public Bar(int parameter){
        //Danger
    }
}
```

But now I'm stuck. Bar's constructor has to call `super()` one way or another, but that won't check for duplicates like `Foo.Factory()` does.

What I would really like would be something like:

```
public Bar(int parameter){
    this=Foo.Factory(parameter);
}
```

But that's obviously not valid java.

For now, I have been forced to write a hacky secondary constructor for Foo that also checks for duplicates, and have Bar use that:

```
//Second unused parameter just so the constructors are different
public Foo(int parameter, boolean isEvil){ 
    Foo duplicate= findDuplicate(parameter);
    if (duplicate!=null){
        this.copy(duplicate); //Evilly take on all attributes of duplicate
    }else{
        //Now we have to copy the body of the original constructor. 
        //It has to be kept synched forever, and I can't even call it!
        this.parameter=parameter;
        addToCache(this);
    }
}

Bar(int parameter){
    super(int,true);
}
```

But this has the problem of always creating a new object, which can cause mutability and hashing concerns. Furthermore, anyone not paying attention won't be able to tell that this constructor works differently.

TLDR: How do I make a constructor for a class whose super should only be made via a factory method.

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836510/can-i-derive-from-a-class-that-can-only-be-created-by-a-factory), but in java (also that question had only one answer and it was unsatisfying to both me and OP)

Comment: If the superclass can only be made via factory method, then the subclass can only be made via factory method.  Because a member of the subclass IS a member of the superclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you have two options.

Options 1 is to create a factory method for `bar` instead of a public constructor.

Option 2 is that, instead of making `bar` inherit from `foo`, it instead contains an instance of `foo` as a member.  In the constructor you can call the factory method for `foo`.

Which way you go probably depends on the details.